# Using ordinal variables in rpart and caret without converting to dummy categorical variables

Tags: r, r-caret, rpart

I am trying to create an ordinal regression tree in R using `rpart`, with the predictors mostly being ordinal data, stored as `factor` in R.

When I created the tree using `rpart`, I get something like this:

[image]

where the values are the factor values (E.g. `A170` has labels ranging from -5 to 10).

However, when I use `caret` to `train` the data using `rpart`, when I extract the final model, the tree no longer has ordinal predictors. See below for a sample output tree

[image]

As you see above, it seems the ordinal variable `A170` now has been converted into multiple dummy categorical value, i.e. `A17010` in the second tree is a dummy for `A170` of value `10`.

So, is it possible to retain ordinal variables instead of converting factor variables into multiple binary indicator variables when fitting trees with the `caret` package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start with a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(144)
dat <- data.frame(x=factor(sample(1:6, 10000, replace=TRUE)))
dat$y <- ifelse(dat$x %in% 1:2, runif(10000) < 0.1, ifelse(dat$x %in% 3:4, runif(10000) < 0.4, runif(10000) < 0.7))*1
```

As you note, training with the `rpart` function groups the factor levels together:

```
library(rpart)
rpart(y~x, data=dat)
```

[image]

I was able to reproduce the caret package splitting up the factors into their individual levels using the formula interface to the `train` function:

```
library(caret)
train(y~x, data=dat, method="rpart")$finalModel
```

[image]

The solution I found to avoid splitting factors by level is to input raw data frames to the `train` function instead of using the formula interface:

```
train(x=data.frame(dat$x), y=dat$y, method="rpart")$finalModel
```

[image]