# caret with SNOW not using parallel processor on a particular set of data

Tags: r, r-caret, snow

I have two data frames ([here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5548442/StackOverflow%20attachments/trainFin.RData) for reproducibility) `trainFin1` and `trainFin2`, both sampled from a same bigger dataset.

I'm trying to run cross-validated `rpart` on them using `caret` over multiprocessor using `doSNOW` package.

Interestingly, `trainFin1` was trained nicely across 4 processors (finishing in about 25 seconds). But `trainFin2` seems to be stuck only on one processor (observed in Windows Task Manager window), and I never get to see it finish processing even after almost half an hour.

My code below

```
require(caret)
require(rpart)
load("trainFin.RData")

fitControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 5, repeats = 5)

#setup parallel processing
require(doSNOW)
cl <- makeCluster(4, type = "SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cl)

#train
set.seed(12345)
firstSet <- train(x = trainFin1[, names(trainFin1) != "Happiness"],
                  y = trainFin1$Happiness,
                  method = "rpart2", trControl = fitControl)

set.seed(12345)
secondSet <- train(x = trainFin2[, names(trainFin2) != "Happiness"],
                   y = trainFin2$Happiness,
                   method = "rpart2", trControl = fitControl)

stopCluster(cl)
```

Do note that I avoided use of `formula` in `train` and instead feed it raw data, to avoid `caret` converting my ordinal variables into dummy categorical variables (see answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819407/using-ordinal-variables-in-rpart-and-caret-without-converting-to-dummy-categoric)). When I used `formula` (i.e. `train(Happiness ~ ., data = trainFin2, method = "rpart2", trControl = fitControl)`), there seems to be no issue with parallel processing. But I want to avoid using `formula` as per the other question.

Any suggestions on how I can parallel-process this data without converting the predictors to categorical dummies ?

Comment: If it helps shed any light, looks like running `rpart` on `trainFin2` without `train` also is taking forever to finish...